# How to prevent double quotes from being escaped in JSON code

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

I am outputting Json from my SocialEngine Zend module using the following code:

```
$data = array(
    'response' => 200,
    'body'     => array (
    'username'  =>    'johndoe',
    'userId'    =>     '1234',
    'info'      => array(
        'location'  => 'Germany',
        'age'       => '30'
    )

)
);
$json= Zend_Json::encode($data);

$isPost = $this->getRequest()->isPost()? 'true' : 'false';
$this->_helper->json($json);
```

This returns a JSON code as follows, in which all double quotes are escaped. How can I prevent that from happening?

```
"{\"response\":200,\"body\":{\"username\":\"johndoe\",\"userId\":\"1234\",\"info\":{\"location\":\"Germany\",\"age\":\"30\"}}}"
```

I have tried replacing double quotes with single quotes, but it had no effect

Comment: Think your encoding it twice, try `$this->_helper->json($data);`

Comment: @NigelRen Thanks this solved the problem. Please add this as an answer.